# Not populating the links dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display links dynamically in AngularJs.

My Js Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10228/

Due to some reasons mark up is not populating the values in markup but the values are property coming from controller.

**Markup**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="navCollapsed">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="navCollapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li ng-repeat="leftLink in leftLinks">
                <a href="#!{{leftLink.Url}}">{{leftLink.Text}}</a>
                <li uib-dropdown ng-if="leftLink.subMenus">
                    <a href="#" uib-dropdown-toggle>Hello               
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="subMenu in leftLink.subMenus">
                            <a href="#!{{subMenu.Url}}">{{subMenu.Text}}</a>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular Js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.leftLinks = [
      {
        subMenus: [
          {
            Text: "Profile",
            Url: "/profile"
          },
          {
            Text: "Change Password",
            Url: "/change-password"
          },
          {
            Text: "Logout",
            Url: "#"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
}
```

Comment: angular 1.0.1, seriously?

Comment: I did not know how to make jsfiddle of angularjs so I copied my code in existing one. I really did not check the version at all. I am using 1.6.2 angular version. I am sorry.

Comment: Create a plunkr instead. You're not defining a controller the correct way (this is how you did it in version 1.0.1), and you're not using it anywhere (no ng-controller). Please create a plunkr with the appropriate version of angular.

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in the code. See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10232/

It was not calling the controller, because of this, I changed to `.controller("Myctrl",function ($scope)` and instantiated it on the html `ng-controller="Myctrl"` on the first element. Another error was the variables name it was `leftLink` instead of `leftLinks`.

You have to review your html code, because you can't put the `li` inside another `li` directly, but this doesn't cause error.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller("Myctrl",function ($scope) {
    $scope.leftLinks = 
      {
        subMenus: [
          {
            Text: "Profile",
            Url: "/profile"
          },
          {
            Text: "Change Password",
            Url: "/change-password"
          },
          {
            Text: "Logout",
            Url: "#"
          }
        ]
      };
});
```

Comment: The code that I was using has square brace and in your code, it contains curly brace in the beginning.

Comment: Yes, if you put square brace you are defining an array, but in this case I don't think it's necessary. The leftLinks is an object and subMenus is an array, but if you need you can just index at ng-repeat.